# Principle of virtual work "geometric proof"

Tags: energy, deflection

I spent a full day searching for and trying to understand why in this "proof" of virtual work makes sense. I've come to understand the idea from D'Alambert's principle, but I want to understand why this method is so "obvious"

Dark triangles represent internal and external energy from a virtual displacement/deformation. The light triangles represent the internal and external energy from displacement/deformation. Given that the dark triangles are equal in area to each other and the light triangles are equal in area to each other, somehow the white rectangles under eachother are equal to each other, but I don't understand why.

The relevant slide is given below, but I also found this on youtube where it is asserted. [Here](https://youtu.be/qR8NlrP7_VM?t=455)
[image: visual equality of virtual work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of ways to think about this, a sort of intuitive way (Method 1) and a more formal way (Method 2).

---

### Method 1

You already stated that the dark triangles are equal in area and the light triangles are equal in area. That also means that the the ratio between light and dark is the same for both graphs, that is $\frac{W_P}{W_Q}=\frac{U_P}{U_Q}$.

We can also determine that all the triangles from one graph are similar because they have the same angle. That means we can just scale any of the triangles by some factor and it will match another in the same graph. This includes the whole graph, which is one big triangle.

If we take $W_Q$ and scale it up by $S_1=\frac{P+Q}{Q}=\frac{P}{Q}+1$, we will have the whole graph. We can do the same with the other graph with $S_2=\frac{F_P+F_Q}{F_Q}=\frac{F_P}{F_Q}+1$ to get the whole graph. We know though that $\frac{P}{Q}=\frac{F_P}{F_Q}$ because the ratio of dark to light is the same (the first equation). That means $S_1=S_2$, so the scaling from the dark triangles to the whole graph is the same for each graph. And since we know that the dark triangles are the same area that means that each graph has the same area as a whole. Now it's easy, since we know the light and dark triangles are the same area, that just leaves us with the white rectangles which must also be equal.

---

### Method 2

This approach is based more on equations.
We know:

$$\delta_Q*Q=\Delta L_Q*F_Q\tag{1}$$
$$\delta_P*P=\Delta L_P*F_P\tag{2}$$

We also know that:

$$W_P\propto W_Q\tag{3}$$
$$U_P\propto U_Q\tag{4}$$

And thus:

$$\frac{\delta_Q}{Q}=\frac{\delta_P}{P}\to \delta_Q*P=\delta_P*Q\tag{5}$$
$$\frac{\Delta L_Q}{F_Q}=\frac{\Delta L_P}{F_P}\to \Delta L_Q*F_P=\Delta L_P*F_Q\tag{6}$$

Now if we take $(5)$ and multiply each side by $\delta_P*Q$, we get:

$$(\delta_Q*P)*(\delta_P*Q)=(\delta_P*Q)^2\tag{7}$$

Rearranged:

$$(\delta_Q*Q)*(\delta_P*P)=(\delta_P*Q)^2\tag{8}$$

Insert $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$(\Delta L_Q*F_Q)*(\Delta L_P*F_P)=(\delta_P*Q)^2\tag{9}$$

Rearrange again:

$$(\Delta L_Q*F_P)*(\Delta L_P*F_Q)=(\delta_P*Q)^2\tag{10}$$

Insert $(6)$:

$$(\Delta L_P*F_Q)*(\Delta L_P*F_Q)=(\delta_P*Q)^2\tag{11}$$

And thus:

$$(\Delta L_P*F_Q)^2=(\delta_P*Q)^2$$
$$\Delta L_P*F_Q=\delta_P*Q\tag{12}$$
$$U'_Q=\Delta L_P*F_Q=\delta_P*Q=W'_Q$$
$$U'_Q=W'_Q\tag{13}$$

And there we have it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. Especially for providing both approaches. I don't feel it was immediately obvious at a glance why it was true when this "fact" came up in class and everyone concurred